# Wordpress Cant access wp-login.php

Tags: login

For miskate i change the url of my wordpress on settings -> general. In order to revert this i changed the wp-config.php file and add this too config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','localhost/wordpress');
define('WP_SITEURL','localhost/wordpress');
```

Then i restarted the apache and i hope i could enter again on my admin panel. But everytime i u use the localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php i receive a 404 not found

ideas?

Comment: use http://localhost/wordpress in place of localhost/wordpress

Answer (score 2):

Don't edit your `wp-config.php` file directly.

Instead, with PHPMyAdmin, access your database and check for the table `_options`.  You should see entries there for `site_url` and `home_url` change those values back to what you need

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit it form wp-config.php 
then use

define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');

Answer (score 0):

Try this
1. Clean Cookies and Caches in the Browser
2. rename ".htaccess" file to .htaccess _backup in the "wordpress" folder
3. Open your phpmyadmin then click on your database, select table "options"
4. Edit siteurl and type correct url in option_value field.
[image]

Save.

if not working, try rename all plugin folder to disable it at /wp-content/plugins/

Good luck